# How to express the beautifulness for the view of sunset behind the sea?

Tags: phrase-request

Does this express the meaning:

> Besonders schön war der Anblick beim Sonnenuntergang Hinter dem Meer, als ob es das Paradies war.

Comment: There's an old german Schlager "Die Capri-Fischer" which contains the well known line "Wenn bei Capri die rote Sonne im Meer versinkt..." Because of this song, I think in German the term "Die Sonne versinkt im Meer" is very common for the sunset at the sea.

Comment: @close-voters According to [this Meta-Post](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1359/) the question is on-topic.

Comment: http://www.inkognito.de/images/articles/ed8577ac04b3d3255a5d59211664b87c_5.jpg?sCoreId=f10b98396267c75f4759aef4de2f8123

Comment: @IQV, that is your opinion.

Comment: @IQV danke - jetzt habe ich einen Ohrwurm >.<

Comment: War das nicht "Wenn bei Capri die rote Flotte im Meer versinkt"?

Answer (score 1):

This would be correct:

> Besonders schön war der Anblick, wie die Sonne langsam im Meer versank.

Comment: This does sound a bit bumpy to me. I would rather say *Besonders schön war der Anblick der langsam im Meer versinkenden Sonne*.

Comment: ... or maybe *[...] langsam hinter dem Meer versinkenden [...]*. More astronomically correct but less poetic.